# Ionic : emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, ionic-framework

I created an app with ionic, build in android and then when I run "ionic emulate android" I receive the following error :

"emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined"

I read on internet and most of them says that I need to install ARM EABI v7a System Image. I have android studio, I opened the sdk and install all package (included ARM EABI v7a System Image) for all the version of android (4.2.1, 4.2.2 etc).

Firstly How can I view the version of android that I am using in ionic?

Second, How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

When I first started android programming, I encountered this issue.

What I did to fix it was:

On Windows:

```
Open Command Prompt.

Type:

setx -m ANDROID_SDK_ROOT '--path--to--sdk--'
```

On Mac/Linux:

```
Open Terminal/Shell.

Type:

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='--path--to--sdk--'
```

Replace --path--to--sdk-- with your sdk path.

Comment: Where should the path point to? I have sdk within the folder with my AOSP sources, but then the emulator suggests there should be system-images in that directory, which would point to devtools. None of which satisfied the bastard though. :(

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this error recently & i've found that **the real problem is ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set to wrong path**.

> It ( **ANDROID_HOME** ) should point to the path, where ***SDK Manager.exe*** & ***AVD
>   Manager.exe*** available.